# 応答ファイルを使ったサイレントインストールについて

Tags: windows

下記のコマンドで応答ファイルを作成し、応答ファイル使ってサイレントインストールを行った所、ResultCode=-3でエラーになってしまいます。
このエラーコードは応答ファイルに必要なデータがないのが原因とのことですが、応答ファイルを作成したマシンとサイレントインストールを行ったマシンは同じであり、システムの違いなどはありません。考えられる原因は何かありますでしょうか？
環境はwindows10 proです。

```
> hogeapp.exe /r /f1"c:\setup.iss"
> hogeapp.exe /s /f1"c:\setup.iss" /f2"c:\test.log"
```

**test.log**

```
[ResponseResult]
ResultCode=-3
```

Answer (score 1):

アンインストールせずに続けてサイレントインストールを行っていませんか？

初回インストールとインストール済み環境へのインストールは処理手順が変わることが多いでしょう。

初回インストールに伴って自動的に作られる応答ファイルでは、そうした状況に対応できないのでは？

以下のような対処が考えられます。

- いったんアンインストールしてからサイレントインストールする
- インストールされていない他のPCでサイレントインストールする
- インストール済み環境へのインストールの応答ファイルも作って、
  別途インストール有無をチェックして指定する応答ファイルを切り替える

---

InstallShieldのFAQ記事
[01745 : サイレントインストールを行う方法](https://tec-world.networld.co.jp/faq/show/1745)

> 1.コマンドラインから /r オプションを指定してインストールを実行し、応答ファイルを作成します
>
> setup.exe /r
>
> ※ダイアログで操作した内容が、自動的に応答ファイルへ記録されます
>
> 2.Setup.iss（応答ファイル）が Windows フォルダー（c:\windows）に作成されていることを確認します
>
> ※応答ファイル作成後は、製品がインストールされた状態となっています。必要に応じて、アンインストールを行ってください。

類似の現象と思われる記事
[11.2.3 インストール型クライアントのサイレントインストール](https://software.fujitsu.com/jp/manual/manualfiles/M070166/B1WW8131/02Z200/dti11/dti00160.html)

> V13.2.0の検疫クライアントをすでにインストールしている場合は、エラーとなります。\Disk1\setup.logファイルには以下のように出力されます。
>
> ```
> [InstallShield Silent]
> Version=v7.00
> File=Log File
> [ResponseResult]
> ResultCode=-3
> ```

[付録B サイレントインストール](https://software.fujitsu.com/jp/manual/manualfiles/m110011/b1ws0925/02z200/b0925-b-00-00.html)

> ログファイルの確認と対処
>   - インストール結果の確認
>   　ログファイルを開き、[ResponseResult]セクションの“ResultCode”を参照してください。
>   　以下に復帰値の意味を記載します。
>
> ```
> -3 対象システムの環境により、応答ファイルと異なるシーケンスで実行された場合
>      ・インストールフォルダ配下にInterstageの資源が残っている、またはInterstageがインストール済
>      ・ディスク容量不足
>      ・排他ソフトウェアが存在
>      ・異なるバージョン・レベル／エディション、またはサーバパッケージのインストーラを用いて作成した応答ファイルを指定した場合。
> ```